# Zipping files preserving the directory structure

Tags: .net-3.5, zip

I am using the DotNetZip DLL(http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) from codeplex to zip some files in my program.

Problem I am facing is after zipping the files it is preserving the directory structure and when I am extracting the zip file all the parent folders are getting created again and then only I am able to view the file. It is very annoying when the source file exists in

So, if I am zipping a file from g:\Archive\LogFiles\W3SVC1\abc.log and creating 'abc.zip' file after extracting it, folders Archive\LogFiles\W3SVC1\ are getting created and then only I am able to see abc.log file. Here 'g:' is the name of my shared drive.

I want to get rid of all these parent folders so that I can straight away extract and reach to the zipped file and open it. I have checked the Path property of the Zipped file and it is showing Archive\LogFiles\W3SVC1. Somehow I need to remove this programatically but not finding any option easily.

Code I am using is like this:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    if (fileExtension != null)
    {
        zip.AddFiles(from f in sourceDir.GetFiles() where f.FullName.EndsWith(fileExtension) select f.FullName);
    }
    else
    {
        zip.AddFiles(from f in sourceDir.GetFiles() select f.FullName);
    }
    zip.Save(DestinationDir + OutFileName);
}
```

I have also tried the overload method of Addfiles by setting the reserveDirectoryHierarchy to 'false' but no benefit.

Please let me know what to do.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not calling the overload method of Addfiles properly. instead of Null I passed empty string and now it is not preserving the directory structure. 
so the updated code is like below:

```
if (fileExtension != null)
                {
                    zip.AddFiles(from f in sourceDir.GetFiles() where f.FullName.EndsWith(fileExtension) select f.FullName,false,"");

                }
                else
                {
                    zip.AddFiles(from f in sourceDir.GetFiles() select f.FullName,false,"");
                }
                zip.Save(DestinationDir + OutFileName);
```