# How to batch zip files without WinRAR, Winzip, or 7zip?

Tags: batch-file, compression, zip

I am trying to use a batch file to zip all the files and folders in a particular directory into one zipped folder *without* using WinRAR, WinZip or 7Zip.

More specifically: 
Let's say I have a folder called Files\
I would like to create a batch file that zips everything in Files\ to a new .zip file *inside* the Files\ folder called something like "MyZippedFile.zip".

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A VBS script can archive to .ZIP - why can't you use an archiver?

Comment: I can't use an archiver because the people who will be using the script will likely not have any archivers installed on their computers... - is that not a problem?

Comment: It's just that an archiver is an important tool in a computer, and free ones are good.

Answer (score 0):

Zips are folders. This copies from one fodler to another.

```
'Zip.vbs - needs an existing zip file
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
Msgbox "Finished"

'Unzip.vbs - needs existing unzip directory
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set DestFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(1))
Set SrcFldr=objShell.NameSpace(Ag(0))
Set FldrItems=SrcFldr.Items
DestFldr.CopyHere FldrItems, &H214
Msgbox "Finished"

'CreateBlankZip.vbs
Set Ag=Wscript.Arguments
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Ag(0), 8, vbtrue)
BlankZip = "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6)
For x = 0 to 17
    BlankZip = BlankZip & Chr(0)
Next
ts.Write BlankZip
```

Comment: Hi David - this seems extremely helpful, but I still can't seem to get it working... I apologize for my ignorance. Is this script you wrote suppposed to be in a .vbs or a .bat file? And when you say " 'Zip.vbs - needs an existing zip file" and " 'Unzip.vbs - needs an existing unzip directory ", and 'CreateBlankZip.vbs" - are those separate files that I would need to create or is this one big file?

Answer (score 0):

I created the VBS script found at [zipping files from different folders preserving the directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414611/zipping-files-from-different-folders-preserving-the-directory-structure) to backup directories **and** files using only the built in widows compression functionality.  It only zips files and folders, no unzipping.  Keeps the folders intact.

Put the code in a file (e.g. `BackZip.vbs`) and execute it with `wscript.exe` which is included in most computers with .NET.  (e.g. `wscript.exe BackZip.vbs /X "C:\My Folder\"`)  It only needs .NET revision 2.0 or more, which was released in 2005.

A lot of the code revolves around handling individual files, but if you're only doing folders you could remove a lot of the code.